# lodash _.template alternative native

Tags: javascript, angular, underscore.js, lodash

I need to take off lodash of my angular2 webpack application, and the last function to finish this task is the "_.template".
I need to an alternative for _.template, in raw javascript.

lodash template
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/template.js

```
    private create() : string {

    let compile = _.template(this.url); <---- i need change this

    return compile(this.params);
}
```

Somebody can help me?

**UPDATE**
I resolve with this code.

```
public static template(url:string, params: any){
    var urlResult = url;

    for(var key in params){
        urlResult = urlResult.replace("${"+key+"}", params[key]);
    }

    return urlResult;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L14748

Comment: i see this, but this function have a many dependencies.
i need to reconstruct this em raw javascript or use any function of angular2, but i not know fucntion to do this,

Comment: Did you consider javascript Template literals? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: template literals with var string not work in angular2,

Comment: You can use [lodash.template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.template) and for browser side support you can browserify it.